# Recursive square structure which can grow

Tags: javascript, recursion, canvas

I am trying to make a structure which begins with a single square. This square could move and stick to itself other squares. Now, here comes the sticky part when the square gains enough squares to increase its size, it should increase its size. 
The sticked squares can also stick other squares and can grow. How am I supposed to make this structure?

[image]

Does it require recursion?

Comment: Depends on your initial implementation, however recursion is a tricky thing. Usually, if this is not some situation, that demands only recursive solution, you should avoid it. If you are speaking about agar.io type of elements interaction, it's not necessary at all. You can just use the good old '+' operator.

Comment: If your elements have to be squares only, but can stick up to each other in any way, you can use addition as well, but you might want to add diagonals, and calculate the side length from it.

Comment: it is kind of like blockor.io. the site is down but you can see the images. @Animus

Comment: What have you tried yourself?